# Is it possible to combine using PyPy and CPython?

Tags: python, cpython, pypy

PyPy is a good interpreter compared with CPython. However, PyPy is incompatible with several packages and extremely slow when there are some requirements that need executing dynamically generated code. Therefore, is there any possible solution to call PyPy through CPython? In this way, I can only run some performance-sensitive codes in PyPy and continually run other codes in CPython.

Comment: Are you mixing up CPython and Cython?

Comment: Sorry, I was confused about the definition of CPython and Cython. I have updated the problem description.

Comment: The two duplicates I've linked describe attempts to do this both ways round. The answer is "not really/not easily/not in a well-integrated way"